# Server currently unavailable for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, graylog

### Background

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 clean VM, and I am trying to install the latest version of graylog on it. Unfortunately, it is failing.

### What did I do?

First I created a clean VM with the afore mentioned OS. 
Then I followed the official instructions step by step:

http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/installation/os/ubuntu.html

I installed the prerequisites, mongo DB, ElasticSearch and last but not least, Graylog 2.4.

I also configured `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` to have `cluster.name: graylog` ( before installing graylog ).

### Graylog conifg

Now, we both know graylog won't start out of the box. You need to do some config. My configuration for `/etc/graylog/server/server.conf` is really simple:

```
rest_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/
web_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000/
```

That's it. 
I also created the necessary keys and passwords as usual.

### What's the problem

When I connect to my server via its public IP with port 9000, I get the following error message:

> We are experiencing problems connecting to the Graylog server running on http://10.0.0.11:9000/api/. Please verify that the server is healthy and working correctly.
>
> You will be automatically redirected to the previous page once we can connect to the server.
>
> Do you need a hand? We can help you.

Following are the details:

> Error message
>       Request has been terminated
>       Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
>   Original Request
>       GET http://10.0.0.11:9000/api/system/sessions
>   Status code
>       undefined
>   Full error message
>       Error: Request has been terminated
>       Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

I can access the web page, but I immediately see the given error. I have another instance configured the same way but with graylog 2.2 and it never gave me any trouble.

### What did you try to solve the problem?

My first idea was to check the health of the services. When I run `sudo systemctl status XXXX`, replacing XXXX with `mongod`, `elasticsearch` and `graylog-server` they all are active and running.

I also checked for similar errors in this forum but they are for different OSs so I am kinda lost here.

### GIve me some specs!

Following are the specs of my OS (`lsb_release -a`):

> No LSB modules are available.
>   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
>   Release:        16.04
>   Codename:       xenial

And the browser I am using:

> Firefox Quantum
>   60.0 ( 64-bit )

### Questions

1. Did I miss come config step?
2. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What did you set `web_endpoint_uri` to?

Comment: I don't have `web_endpoint_uri` set. According to the docs, it will use `rest_transport_uri` which is set to the Public IP of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

This was a configuration issue. I fixed it by using the following config:

```
rest_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/
web_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000/
#web_endpoint_uri =
rest_transport_uri = http://<AZURE_PUBLIC_IP>:9000/api/
```

Do note that `web_endpoint_uri` is commented. 
I still don't quite get how all the pieces work, but this seems to have done the trick.

As a bonus round, this is equivalent to the following:

```
rest_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/
web_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:9000/
web_endpoint_uri = http://<AZURE_PUBLIC_IP>:9000/api/
```